# React Nested Router: Remove Parent Route from link

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-router-dom

So, I've been working with `react-router-dom`. My problem is that I am working with nested routes. I want to make it route without parent route in URL.
My Current Code is.
`<Route path= "/dashboard/some-page" component={someComponent}/>` and What I want to do is
`<Route path="/some-page" component={someComponent}/>`.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you can't. `react-router-dom` only matches the full path. In the upcoming version 6, they have added that functionality, but it's currently still in beta. It's not a drop in replacement; the API has changed, so will require a bit of restructuring.

https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v6-pre/#nested-routes-and-layouts